# Set Windows 10 volume box (notification) timer

Tags: windows-10, audio, notifications, ease-of-access

The timer for Windows 10 notification box for the volume level (figure above) is set to 5 seconds by default. Its duration can be modified in *Settings > Ease of Access > Display* by changing the value of *Show notification for*, but the minumum is 5 seconds and I find it too much for me.

Is it possible to change the value of a registry key and manually set the desired duration?

Reference pictures:

[image]

[image]